# Should I use Custom Authorizer or Lambda@edge to secure my API

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-api-gateway, aws-lambda-edge

I want to lock down my API and I am wondering the best way to do this.

I have approx 20 micro services that are using API gateway with a proxy that has a custom authorizer.  This has a cloudfront distribution.

The issue with sending through an authorisation token (bearer) is that I am not getting the caching benefits of cloudfront for every new user.  Therefore I am subject to two sets of cold starts which makes cloudfront pointless.

Should I switch to a lambda@edge authorisation method or should I continue with a custom authorizer.  I would like to know the benefits of either approach.  There is concern that if we use lambda@edge authorisation technique then we are leaving the proxy api (non cloudfront) wide open.

Thanks for your help!